# Text in absolutely positioned div is overlapping

Tags: html, css

In the below code snippet, the div elements (.main > div) are relatively positioned and are floated left.

Because of the relative positioning, the div elements (.main > div) are placed next to each other.

The span elements are under the div elements (.main > div > span)

The span elements are positioned absolutely so as to centre the text (Food, Health).

But the issue I am facing is that the text is overlapping.

As per my understanding, an absolutely positioned element (.main > div > span) should be positioned with respect to its relatively or absolutely positioned container (.main > div).

So why are elements overlapping. Not just the span elements, but also the div elements (which are relatively positioned) overlapping.

I tried to figure this issue by myself, but couldn't figure out the problem.

I searched for similar StackOverflow questions, but they did not provide the solution.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  height: 5%;
  border: 1px solid thistle;
}

.main > div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


.main > div > span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main">
   <div><span>Food</span></div>
   <div><span>Health</span></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, though in this case where the `div`'s is floated, they will collapse into a width of 0, as none of the `div`'s has any normal flowing content, hence your absolute `span`'s overlap.

In below sample I gave the `div`'s a width, and now you can see it works how you expected.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  height: 5%;
  border: 1px solid thistle;
}

.main > div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;                 /*  added a width  */
}


.main > div > span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main">
   <div><span>Food</span></div>
   <div><span>Health</span></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that each of your `position:absolute;` elements are removed from the DOM's native flow, and positioned absolutely to their parent element. Since they both have the same positioning, they are placed over top of each other. Use `position:relative` to position the elements relative to their native position in the DOM.

Comment: The DOM has no "native flow". What you are referring to is the "normal flow" of CSS positioned elements in which the DOM plays no part beyond the document node order of the elements. https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#normal-flow